# How can I do Reduction in Nested Loops using OpenMP?

Tags: c++, openmp, reduction

I am trying to parallelize nested loops:

```
#pragma omp parallel reduction(+: Q)
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++)
    {
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < num_vertices; j++)
        {
           if (coms[i] == coms[j])
           {
               edge_t edge(i,j);
               int val = 0;
               if (edgeSet.find(edge) != edgeSet.end()) val = 1;
               Q += val - (double(degrees[i] * degrees[j])/double(2*num_edges));
           }
        }
        if (i % 1000000 == 0) std::cout << "calculated for " << i << " nodes" << std::endl;
   }
```

The program runs quite slow. Is there anything I can do to improve the performance? Am I using `reduction` properly?
As far as I understand, having `#pragma omp parallel reduction(+: Q)` in the inner loop would affect the performance negatively since it would create and destroy threads for each iteration of the outer loop.

I've tested the program on 64 `Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4650 2.7 GHz` cores for a dataset that has around 4M vertices(`num_vertices = 4000000`). The program ran over an hour, but still not completed. The problem is that `num_vertices` can be as many as 110M for other datasets. Therefore, I am wondering if there is any trick to decrease multithreading overhead and increase the performance of parallelization.

Comment: What is _quite slow_? Provide some data. How many threads? How many physical/virtual cores? How large is `num_vertices`? What are the measured times for a single thread and multiple threads? What are your compilation flags? Which compiler vendor and version? Which system?

Comment: @DanielsaysreinstateMonica please, see the edited question.

Comment: When I look at the code I see that it really only does any work when `coms[i] == coms[j]`.  So I thinks to meself, what can be done to find only those elements of `coms` where that is (likely to be) true.  Sorting ?  Indexing ?  ???  I haven't a clue, but that's where I'd start looking for performance improvements.  As it stands your program seems to have quadratic complexity and I don't like them odds when scaling from `4M^2` to `110M^2`.

Comment: So what are the runtimes for 1 thread and 64 threads? You still did not give any evidence of poor scalability. If the runtime for 1 thread is 6400 hours, the runtime for 64 threads will 100 hours in the optimal case. BTW I suggest to use `dynamic` scheduling, the `static` may scale poorly due to `if (coms[i] == coms[j])` condition.

Comment: Well 4M squared is a rather large value. You could consider adding a collapse clause, it might help in certain cases, depending on your input. But as it has been suggested before, is there no way to avoid the O(N^2) complexity? I don't know what kind of information you have about the problem beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You simply forget to distribute the work across the threads.

You create a *parallel region* with the `parallel` directive, which means a number of threads (default: the numbers of cores your OS sees) are created from this point on. Each thread execute **all** iterations (i.e num_vertices * num_vertices iterations) in your code below, which explains why you don't get any speedup.

```c
#pragma omp parallel reduction(+: Q)
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++)
    {
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < num_vertices; j++)
        {
        }
     }
```

This happens because you don't tell OpenMP to **share** the work (i.e split the iteration set across the available threads). Work sharing of a `for` loop is requested with `#pragma omp for` just before the loop `i` for instance, which would distribute equally the iterations `i` over the threads. Without a `schedule` clause, thread 0 deals with iterations [0,..,num_vertices/T-1], thread 1 has iterations [num_vertices/T, .., 2*num_vertices/T-1], ..., where T is the number of threads in the parallel region.

As your iteration domain is a square, you could increase the number of iterations to distribute (in case num_vertices is small) with `#pragma omp for collapse(2)` to distribute iterations in `i` and `j`.

Finally, as your `#pragma omp for` would immediately follow your `#pragma omp parallel` , people usually use the shorthand `parallel for` to combine the two directives.

Your program would then read:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+: Q)
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < num_vertices; i++)
    {
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < num_vertices; j++)
        {
        }
     }
```